# Sending data to Queue and listening for data in same function

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, message-queue

I'm trying to create a function where I send a JMS message to a queue and listen on a different queue the response. The two queues are different and I want to return when the response is available from the second queue. How should I do this? Should I do while(true)? Doing a MessageListener seems like forces me to call another function to receive the answer when I want to return the function with the response that sent the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but I think the simplest way in JMS 1.1 is using the [javax.jms.QueueRequestor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueRequestor.html). This is a simple interface which takes care of just about all the boiler plate code you'd use with a manual request/response pattern. For example, the requestor might look like this:

```
InitialContext initialContext new InitialContext();
Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("myQueue");
QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
QueueConnection connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
connection.start();
QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
QueueRequestor queueRequestor = new QueueRequestor(session, queue);
TextMessage request = session.createTextMessage("Hello, World!");
TextMessage reply = (TextMessage) queueRequestor.request(request);
queueRequestor.close();
```

Then the component which gets the message and provides the response might look like this:

```
InitialContext initialContext new InitialContext();
Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("myQueue");
QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
QueueConnection connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
connection.start();
QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
TextMessage request = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive();
TextMessage reply = session.createTextMessage("reply: " + request.getText());
Destination replyTo = request.getJMSReplyTo();
try (MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(replyTo)) {
    producer.send(reply);
}
```

If you're JMS provider supports 2.0 then you could do something like this for the client sending the request:

```
InitialContext initialContext new InitialContext();
Queue requestQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("requestQueue");
Queue responseQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("responseQueue");
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
String correlationID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
JMSContext context = cf.createContext();
context.createProducer().setJMSCorrelationID(correlationID).send(requestQueue, context.createTextMessage("requestMessage"));
Message reply = context.createConsumer(responseQueue, "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationID + "'").receive();
```

And something like this for the responder:

```
InitialContext initialContext new InitialContext();
Queue requestQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("requestQueue");
Queue responseQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("responseQueue");
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
JMSContext context = cf.createContext();
Message request = context.createConsumer(requestQueue).receive();
context.createProducer().setJMSCorrelationID(request.getJMSCorrelationID()).send(responseQueue, context.createTextMessage("responseMessage"));
```

Comment: Of course JMSContext or ConnectionFactory can be injected in the context of an application server :)